# HQL: Hibernate query with ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

I have a question with HQL query and hibernate.

I have a user class and a role class. A user can have many roles. So I have a ManyToMany relatation like this:

In user class:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@oinTable(name = "PORTAIL_USERROLE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USERID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set<Portailrole> getPortailroles() {
    return this.portailroles;
}
```

In role class:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "PORTAIL_USERROLE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USERID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set<Portailuser> getPortailusers() {
    return this.portailusers;
}
```

This mapping has created a 3rd table (PORTAIL_USERROLE) where relations are stocked.
All work fine like this. When I have a user, I retrieve roles.

But, my question is: in a HQL query, how can I get all users which have a specific role ? Any class represents PORTAIL_USERROLE table so I don't know how to make my HQL query.

Comment: when Pascal Thivent edited this question he changed JoinTable to oinTable and un capitalised a perfectly valid sentence before then removing the 'Thank you' from the end.  Seriously what was the point, it made the question less readable?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from Portailuser u join u.portailroles r where r.name=:roleName
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't think that hibernate manages manyToMany like this.

Answer (score 2):

you can use 
    @WhereJoinTable
 Like this:

```
 @JoinTable(name = "OFFICE_USER_POSITION", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "POST_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")})
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "primary_flag='" + YES + "' and del_flag='" + DEL_FLAG_NORMAL + "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these features for one or more `@MoneyToMany` related entities

```
List<User> findUsersByRoles_RoleIdIn(List<Integer> roles);

List<User> findUserByRoles_RoleIdInAndHoldings_HoldingId(List<Integer> roles, Integer holding);
```